# Unable to update values in CSV file imported into GUI using Tkinter

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I'm not able to update any values in the imported CSV file into GUI. I'm able to open the CSV and add a new column, but when I try to select a value and update it to my desired value I'm not able to do that.

Also, I have made a button for updating the values, but when I select the existing value and click on the update row button nothing happens.

My code is below:

```
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

csv_data = pd.DataFrame()
csv_text = None
entry_values = {}

def create_gui():
    global csv_data, csv_text, entry_values

    def open_csv():
        global csv_data
        csv_path = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(title='Select CSV File', filetypes=[('CSV Files', '*.csv')])
        if csv_path:
            csv_data = pd.read_csv(csv_path)
            update_csv_display()
            create_entry_widgets()

   def display_csv():
       if csv_data is not None:
           for col in range(len(csv_data.columns)):
               label = tk.Label(csv_frame, text=csv_data.columns[col])
               label.pack()

               for row in range(len(csv_data)):
                    entry = tk.Entry(csv_frame)
                    entry.pack()
                    entry.insert(tk.END, str(csv_data.iloc[row, col]))

   def save_csv():
       global csv_data
       if csv_data is not None:
           csv_path = tk.filedialog.asksaveasfilename(title='Save CSV File', defaultextension='.csv', filetypes=[('CSV Files', '*.csv')])
           csv_data.to_csv(csv_path, index=False)
           print("CSV file saved successfully.")

   def add_column():
        global csv_data
        if csv_data is not None:
            column_name = entry_column.get()
            csv_data[column_name] = ''
            update_csv_display()
            create_entry_widgets()

   def update_csv_display():
        csv_text.delete(1.0, tk.END)
        csv_text.insert(tk.END, csv_data.to_string())

   def create_entry_widgets():
        global entry_values
        for col in csv_data.columns:
            entry_values[col] = StringVar()
            entry = Entry(csv_frame, textvariable=entry_values[col])
            entry.pack(padx=5, pady=5)


   def update_selected_row(event=None):
        print("selected row")
        global csv_data
        selected_items = my_tree.selection()
        print(selected_items)
        if selected_items:
            selected_row = selected_items[0]
            print(selected_row)
            for col, value in entry_values.items():
                print(f"{col}: {value.get()}")
                entry_values[col].set(csv_data.at[selected_row, col])

    def update_csv_data():
        global csv_data
        selected_items = my_tree.selection()
        if selected_items:
            selected_row = selected_items[0]
            for col in csv_data.columns:
                new_value = entry_values[col].get()
                csv_data.at[selected_row, col] = new_value
            update_csv_display()

   global csv_text
   root = Tk()
   root.geometry("1000x800")

   # Create a frame for the CSV data
   csv_frame = Frame(root)
   csv_frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=10, pady=10)

   csv_text = Text(csv_frame, width=120, height=50)
   csv_text.pack()

    # Create a button to open the CSV file
   csv_button = Button(csv_frame, text='Open CSV', command=open_csv)
   csv_button.pack(pady=10)

    # Create a button to save the CSV file
   save_csv_button = Button(csv_frame, text='Save CSV', command=save_csv)
   save_csv_button.pack(pady=10)

   # Add a column entry field and button for manual column addition
   add_column_frame = Frame(csv_frame)
   add_column_frame.pack(pady=10)

   entry_column = Entry(add_column_frame, width=20)
   entry_column.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5)

   add_column_button = Button(add_column_frame, text='Add Column', command=add_column)
   add_column_button.pack(side=LEFT)

  # Create a Treeview for displaying CSV data
   my_tree = ttk.Treeview(root)
   my_tree.pack(pady=20)

   my_tree.bind("<<TreeviewSelect>>", update_selected_row)

   update_row_button = Button(root, text='Update Row', command=update_selected_row)
   update_row_button.pack(padx=5, pady=5)

   save_changes_button = Button(root, text='Save Changes', command=update_csv_data)
   save_changes_button.pack(padx=5, pady=5)


   root.mainloop()

create_gui()
```

Please let me know where I am wrong and what I am missing.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: there is problem with layout - I can't see button `Add Column`

Comment: I made smaller `Text` and now I see `Add Column` but it doesn't work correctly - it always add `Entry` for all columns. If I try to add column with the same name then it creates second `Entry` but it should keep only one `Entry`. If I create second column with different name then it adds two new `Entry` but it doesn't remove old `Entry` and I have 3 `Entry` instead of 2 `Entry`. You should keep all `Entry` on list and remove them when before you create all new `Entry`

Comment: when it loads CSV then it doesn't create items in `TreeView` so I can't select row for update - and it can't save data in file.

Comment: I added code which add items to `TreeView` but your code has another problem - it gets `selected_row` which is `row_id` in `TreeView`, but you need row number in `csv_data`. So you need `row_number = my_tree.item(selected_row)['text']`

Comment: frankly, your buttons `Update Row` and `Save Changes` because `Update Row` doesn't get data from `Entry` and it doesn't update row in `DataFrame` - but it gets data from  `DataFrame` and update `Entry`. And `Save Changes` doesn't save `DataFrame` in file with new data but it gets values from `Entry` and it updates row in `DataFrame`

Comment: BTW: there is module [pandastable](https://pandastable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html) to display and edit `DataFrame` in `tkinter`. You may see screenshot in my post [Tkinter PandasTable Examples](https://blog.furas.pl/python-tkinter-pandastable-examples-gb.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your doesn't work as you describe.

---

First: it doesn't create items in `Treeview` when it loads `CSV` so buttons `Update Row` and `Save Changes` can't work.

I add row numbers in `Treeview` when I load file:
(but first I remove old items - so when I load second file then it removes rows from first file):

```
# remove old items in Treeview

for item in my_tree.get_children():
    my_tree.delete(item)

# add new items in Treeview            

for index in range(len(csv_data)):
    my_tree.insert("", "end", text=index)
```

---

Second: You have code to get selected items from `Treeview` but it gives you `row ID` in `Treeview` but you need `row number` in `DataFrame`.

I use this:

```
selected_row_id = selected_items[0]
print('Treeview row id:', selected_row_id)

selected_row = my_tree.item(selected_row_id)['text']
print('DataFrame row number:', selected_row)
```

---

Other problem: button `Add column` creates new `Entry` for all existing columns - so it adds many times `Entry` for the same columns. It should add only one Entry - only for new column - or it should remove all previous `Entry` before adding again `Entry` for all columns.

I remove all `Entry`. To make it simpler I create new `Frame` (named `rows_frame`_ and put all `Entry` in this `Frame`. And later I remove all children.

```
# remove all widgets from Frame

for item in rows_frame.winfo_children():
    item.destroy()
```

Because it is easy so I add also `Label` with column's names.
I also add `Label` with column name.

---

[image]

My full working code:

```
import tkinter as tk   # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import ttk
import pandas as pd

# --- constants ---  # PEP8: `UPPER_CASE_NAMES`

DEBUG = True

# --- classes ---

# --- functions ---

def create_gui():
    global csv_data 
    global csv_text
    global entry_values
    global entry_column
    global csv_frame
    global my_tree

    def open_csv():
        """Read CSV file."""
        
        global csv_data
        
        if DEBUG:
           print('[DEBUG] open_csv()')
               
        csv_path = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(title='Select CSV File', filetypes=[('CSV Files', '*.csv')])
        
        if csv_path:
            csv_data = pd.read_csv(csv_path)
            update_csv_display()
            create_entry_widgets()

            # remove old items in Treeview
            for item in my_tree.get_children():
                my_tree.delete(item)

            # add new items in Treeview            
            for index in range(len(csv_data)):
                my_tree.insert("", "end", text=index)

    def save_csv():
        """Write CSV file."""

        global csv_data

        if DEBUG:
           print('[DEBUG] save_csv()')
       
        if csv_data is not None:
            csv_path = tk.filedialog.asksaveasfilename(title='Save CSV File', defaultextension='.csv', filetypes=[('CSV Files', '*.csv')])
            csv_data.to_csv(csv_path, index=False)
            print("CSV file saved successfully.")

    def display_csv():
        """Display DataFrame in ???"""

        if DEBUG:
           print('[DEBUG] display_csv()')

        if csv_data is not None:
            for col in range(len(csv_data.columns)):
               label = tk.Label(csv_frame, text=csv_data.columns[col])
               label.pack()

               for row in range(len(csv_data)):
                    entry = tk.Entry(csv_frame)
                    entry.pack()
                    entry.insert(tk.END, str(csv_data.iloc[row, col]))

    def add_column():
        """Add new column to DataFrame and (re)create all Entry."""
        
        global csv_data

        if DEBUG:
           print('[DEBUG] add_column()')
        
        if csv_data is not None:
            column_name = entry_column.get()
            column_name = column_name.strip()  # remove spaces at the ends.
            if column_name:  # check if name is not empty
                csv_data[column_name] = ''
                update_csv_display()
                create_entry_widgets()

    def update_csv_display():
        """Display DataFrame information in Text."""

        if DEBUG:
           print('[DEBUG] update_csv_display()')

        csv_text.delete(1.0, tk.END)
        csv_text.insert(tk.END, csv_data.to_string())

    def create_entry_widgets():
        """(Re)Create Entry for all rows."""
        
        global entry_values
        global entry_widgets

        if DEBUG:
           print('[DEBUG] create_entry_widgets()')
        
        # remove all widgets from Frame
        for item in rows_frame.winfo_children():
            item.destroy()
            
        # create again all Entry widgets and all Treeview rows
        for index, col in enumerate(csv_data.columns):
            print('col:', col)
            entry_values[col] = tk.StringVar()

            entry = tk.Label(rows_frame, text=f"{col}:")
            entry.grid(row=index, column=0, sticky='e')

            entry = tk.Entry(rows_frame, textvariable=entry_values[col])
            entry.grid(row=index, column=1)

    def get_selected_row_from_csv(event=None):
        """Get data from `csv_data` put in all `Entry` for row selected in TreeView."""
    
        global csv_data

        if DEBUG:
           print('[DEBUG] get_selected_row_from_csv()')
        
        selected_items = my_tree.selection()
        print('selected_items:', selected_items)
        
        if selected_items:
            selected_row_id = selected_items[0]
            print('Treeview row id:', selected_row_id)
            
            selected_row = my_tree.item(selected_row_id)['text']
            print('DataFrame row number:', selected_row)
            
            for col, value in entry_values.items():
                print(f"{col}: {value.get()}")
                entry_values[col].set(csv_data.at[selected_row, col])

    def update_selected_row_in_csv():
        """Get data from all `Entry` and put in `csv_data` for row selected in TreeView."""
        
        global csv_data

        if DEBUG:
           print('[DEBUG] update_selected_row_in_csv()')
        
        selected_items = my_tree.selection()
        
        if selected_items:
            selected_row_id = selected_items[0]
            print('Treeview row id:', selected_row_id)
            
            selected_row = my_tree.item(selected_row_id)['text']
            print('DataFrame row number:', selected_row)
            
            for col in csv_data.columns:
                csv_data.at[selected_row, col] = entry_values[col].get()
            
            update_csv_display()

    # --- main ---
    
    if DEBUG:
       print('[DEBUG] create_gui()')
    
    root = tk.Tk()
    #root.geometry("1200x600")

    # Create a frame for the CSV data
    csv_frame = tk.Frame(root)
    csv_frame.pack(side="left", padx=10, pady=10)

    csv_text = tk.Text(csv_frame, width=120, height=15)
    csv_text.pack()

    # Create a button to open the CSV file
    csv_button = tk.Button(csv_frame, text='Open CSV', command=open_csv)
    csv_button.pack(pady=10)

    # Create a button to save the CSV file
    save_csv_button = tk.Button(csv_frame, text='Save CSV', command=save_csv)
    save_csv_button.pack(pady=10)

    # Add a column entry field and button for manual column addition
    add_column_frame = tk.Frame(csv_frame)
    add_column_frame.pack(pady=10)

    entry_column = tk.Entry(add_column_frame, width=10)
    entry_column.pack(padx=5, side="left")

    add_column_button = tk.Button(add_column_frame, text='Add Column', command=add_column)
    add_column_button.pack(side="left")

    rows_frame = tk.Frame(csv_frame)
    rows_frame.pack()
    
    # Create a Treeview for displaying CSV data
    my_tree = ttk.Treeview(root)
    my_tree.heading('#0', text='Select Row')
    
    my_tree.pack(pady=20)

    my_tree.bind("<<TreeviewSelect>>", get_selected_row_from_csv)

    update_row_button = tk.Button(root, text='Get selected row from CSV', command=get_selected_row_from_csv)
    update_row_button.pack(padx=5, pady=5)

    save_changes_button = tk.Button(root, text='Update selected row in CSV', command=update_selected_row_in_csv)
    save_changes_button.pack(padx=5, pady=5)

    root.mainloop()

# --- main ---

csv_data = pd.DataFrame()
csv_text = None
entry_values = {}
entry_widgets = []

create_gui()
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Hi @furas, what a lovely solution. It solved my issue, now I'm able to update the data in my imported csv. I have another doubt though, should I ask it here by updating my code or should I post another question?

Comment: Yes. You can post another question. But not on the same previously asked question.

Comment: @KartikeyaKawadkar if you have new problem then you should create new question on new page. In question you may add link to this question - to show that it is continuation. But still you should add all details in question - so other people wouldn't have to visit old question to get all details. And later you can add `@furas` in comment belowe new question and Stackoverflow will send information that there is message for me.