# Unable to drag-&-drop the labels in the entry fields of GUI using Tkinter

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I'm trying to add a window with "labels" in my GUI which is getting created correctly, but I'm not able to drag and drop the labels to the entry fields it seems. I'm able to get the csv, image and other operations correctly, only the drag and drop to the respective entry field is not working properly in my GUI. This is a continuation of this question -
[Unable to update values in CSV file imported into GUI using Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77563748/unable-to-update-values-in-csv-file-imported-into-gui-using-tkinter)

This is my code :

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import ttk
import pandas as pd
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import Frame
from tkinter import Toplevel, Label



DEBUG = True

def create_gui():
   global csv_data 
   global csv_text
   global entry_values
   global entry_column
   global csv_frame
   global my_tree
   global dragged_label
   global canvas
   global label_list

   def open_image():
       image_path = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(title='Select Image')
       image = Image.open(image_path)
       image = image.resize((400, 400))  # Adjust the size as per your preference
       photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
       image_label.configure(image=photo)
       image_label.image = photo


   def open_csv():
       """Read CSV file."""
    
       global csv_data
    
       if DEBUG:
           print('[DEBUG] open_csv()')
           
       csv_path = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(title='Select CSV File', filetypes=[('CSV Files', '*.csv')])
    
       if csv_path:
           csv_data = pd.read_csv(csv_path)
           update_csv_display()
           create_entry_widgets()

           # remove old items in Treeview
           for item in my_tree.get_children():
               my_tree.delete(item)

           # add new items in Treeview            
           for index in range(len(csv_data)):
               my_tree.insert("", "end", text=index)

   def save_csv():
       """Write CSV file."""

       global csv_data

       if DEBUG:
           print('[DEBUG] save_csv()')
   
       if csv_data is not None:
           csv_path = tk.filedialog.asksaveasfilename(title='Save CSV File', defaultextension='.csv', filetypes=[('CSV Files', '*.csv')])
           csv_data.to_csv(csv_path, index=False)
           print("CSV file saved successfully.")

  def display_csv():
      """Display DataFrame in ???"""

      if DEBUG:
          print('[DEBUG] display_csv()')

      if csv_data is not None:
           for col in range(len(csv_data.columns)):
               label = tk.Label(csv_frame, text=csv_data.columns[col])
               label.pack()

               for row in range(len(csv_data)):
                   entry = tk.Entry(csv_frame)
                   entry.pack()
                   entry.insert(tk.END, str(csv_data.iloc[row, col]))

   def add_column():
       """Add new column to DataFrame and (re)create all Entry."""
    
       global csv_data

       if DEBUG:
           print('[DEBUG] add_column()')
    
       if csv_data is not None:
           column_name = entry_column.get()
           column_name = column_name.strip()  # remove spaces at the ends.
           if column_name:  # check if name is not empty
               csv_data[column_name] = ''
               update_csv_display()
               create_entry_widgets()

   def update_csv_display():
       """Display DataFrame information in Text."""

       if DEBUG:
           print('[DEBUG] update_csv_display()')

       csv_text.delete(1.0, tk.END)
       csv_text.insert(tk.END, csv_data.to_string())

   def create_entry_widgets():
       """(Re)Create Entry for all rows."""
    
       global entry_values
       global entry_widgets

       if DEBUG:
           print('[DEBUG] create_entry_widgets()')
    
       # remove all widgets from Frame
       for item in rows_frame.winfo_children():
           item.destroy()
        
       # create again all Entry widgets and all Treeview rows
       for index, col in enumerate(csv_data.columns):
           print('col:', col)
           entry_values[col] = tk.StringVar()

           entry = tk.Label(rows_frame, text=f"{col}:")
           entry.grid(row=index, column=0, sticky='e')

           entry = tk.Entry(rows_frame, textvariable=entry_values[col])
           entry.grid(row=index, column=1)

   def get_selected_row_from_csv(event=None):
       """Get data from `csv_data` put in all `Entry` for row selected in TreeView."""

       global csv_data

       if DEBUG:
           print('[DEBUG] get_selected_row_from_csv()')
    
       selected_items = my_tree.selection()
       print('selected_items:', selected_items)
    
       if selected_items:
           selected_row_id = selected_items[0]
           print('Treeview row id:', selected_row_id)
        
           selected_row = my_tree.item(selected_row_id)['text']
           print('DataFrame row number:', selected_row)
        
           for col, value in entry_values.items():
               print(f"{col}: {value.get()}")
               entry_values[col].set(csv_data.at[selected_row, col])

   def update_selected_row_in_csv():
       """Get data from all `Entry` and put in `csv_data` for row selected in TreeView."""
    
       global csv_data

       if DEBUG:
           print('[DEBUG] update_selected_row_in_csv()')
    
       selected_items = my_tree.selection()
    
       if selected_items:
           selected_row_id = selected_items[0]
           print('Treeview row id:', selected_row_id)
        
           selected_row = my_tree.item(selected_row_id)['text']
           print('DataFrame row number:', selected_row)
        
           for col in csv_data.columns:
               csv_data.at[selected_row, col] = entry_values[col].get()
        
           update_csv_display()


    def create_draggable_labels():
    global canvas, label_list

    def on_label_drag_start(event):
        global dragged_label
        dragged_label = event.widget

    def on_label_drop(event):
        if dragged_label:
            label_text = dragged_label.cget("text")
            # value_to_update = "Some Value"  # Replace with your logic to get the corresponding value
            value_to_update = label_text
            dragged_label.place_forget()

            top = Toplevel(root)
            top.geometry("300x50")
            label = Label(top, text=f"{label_text}: {value_to_update}")
            label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

            x, y = root.winfo_pointerx(), root.winfo_pointery()
            top.geometry(f"+{x}+{y}")

            def on_dragged_label_release(event):
                global dragged_label

                # Find the entry field under the cursor
                entry_under_cursor = root.winfo_containing(event.x_root, event.y_root)

                # Check if the widget under the cursor is an Entry widget
                if isinstance(entry_under_cursor, tk.Entry):
                    # Get the column name from the dragged label
                    col_name = dragged_label.cget("text")

                    # Update the corresponding entry field with the label's value
                    entry_under_cursor.delete(0, tk.END)
                    entry_under_cursor.insert(tk.END, col_name + ": " + value_to_update)

                top.destroy()

            label.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", on_dragged_label_release)


       canvas_frame = tk.Frame(root)
       canvas_frame.pack(side=tk.TOP, padx=10, pady=10)

       canvas = tk.Canvas(canvas_frame, width=800, height=50)
       canvas.pack()

       label_list = []  # List to store labels

       for col_index, col in enumerate([
           "invoice_number",
           "date",
           "time",
           "total",
           "vendor.name",
           "vendor.phone_number",
           "vendor.gst_number",
           "vendor.email",
           "vendor.website",
           "vendor.address",
           "customer.customer_name",
           "customer.phone_number"
       ]):
           label = tk.Label(canvas, text=col, bd=1, relief="solid")
           label.grid(row=0, column=col_index, padx=5)

           label.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", on_label_drag_start)
           label.bind("<B1-Motion>", lambda event, col=col: on_label_drag(event, col))
           label.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", on_label_drop)

           label_list.append(label)  # Store labels in the list

       canvas_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

   def on_label_drag(event, col_name):
       global dragged_label
       x, y = root.winfo_pointerx(), root.winfo_pointery()
       canvas.coords(dragged_label, x, y)

       # Redraw labels
       for col_index, col in enumerate([
           "invoice_number",
           "date",
           "time",
           "total",
           "vendor.name",
           "vendor.phone_number",
           "vendor.gst_number",
           "vendor.email",
           "vendor.website",
           "vendor.address",
           "customer.customer_name",
           "customer.phone_number"
        ]):
            label = tk.Label(canvas, text=col, bd=1, relief="solid")
            label.grid(row=0, column=col_index, padx=5)

        # Redraw dragged label
        canvas.create_window(x, y, anchor=tk.NW, window=dragged_label)



   # --- main ---

   if DEBUG:
      print('[DEBUG] create_gui()')

   root = tk.Tk()
   # root.geometry("1200x800")

   # Create a frame for the image
   image_frame = tk.Frame(root)
   image_frame.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, padx=10, pady=10)

   # Create a label for displaying the image
   image_label = tk.Label(image_frame)
   image_label.pack()

   # Create a button to open the image
   image_button = tk.Button(image_frame, text='Open Image', command=open_image)
   image_button.pack(pady=10)

   # Create a frame for the CSV data
   csv_frame = tk.Frame(root)
   csv_frame.pack(side="left", padx=10, pady=10)

   csv_text = tk.Text(csv_frame, width=160, height=15)
   csv_text.pack()

   # Create a button to open the CSV file
   csv_button = tk.Button(csv_frame, text='Open CSV', command=open_csv)
   csv_button.pack(pady=10)

   # Create a button to save the CSV file
   save_csv_button = tk.Button(csv_frame, text='Save CSV', command=save_csv)
   save_csv_button.pack(pady=10)

   # Add a column entry field and button for manual column addition
   add_column_frame = tk.Frame(csv_frame)
   add_column_frame.pack(pady=10)

   entry_column = tk.Entry(add_column_frame, width=10)
   entry_column.pack(padx=5, side="left")

   add_column_button = tk.Button(add_column_frame, text='Add Column', command=add_column)
   add_column_button.pack(side="left")

   rows_frame = tk.Frame(csv_frame)
   rows_frame.pack()

   # Create a Treeview for displaying CSV data
   my_tree = ttk.Treeview(root)
   my_tree.heading('#0', text='Select Row')

   my_tree.pack(pady=20)

   my_tree.bind("<<TreeviewSelect>>", get_selected_row_from_csv)

   update_row_button = tk.Button(root, text='Get selected row from CSV', command=get_selected_row_from_csv)
   update_row_button.pack(padx=5, pady=5)

   save_changes_button = tk.Button(root, text='Update selected row in CSV', command=update_selected_row_in_csv)
   save_changes_button.pack(padx=5, pady=5)

   create_draggable_labels()
   root.mainloop()

 # --- main ---

 csv_data = pd.DataFrame()
 csv_text = None
 entry_values = {}
 entry_widgets = []

 create_gui()
```

It would be really great and helpful if you could let me know where am I going wrong and where should I make possible changes to get the proper output, Thank you.

Comment: Please try to reduce the amount of code. For example, could you use a few lines of hard-coded data instead of all of the code to read a CSV file? See [mcve] for help.

Comment: Reduce the code as in, should I just add the specific functions? For reading the csv file, there is nothing hard coded, instead there's just one line of command to read it. Can you be more specific with the requirement or can you let me know why I'm not able to drag and drop my labels to the entry fields, thank you.

Comment: Hi @furas, as suggested, can you help me in getting the created labels dragged and dropped in the entry field. Thank you